# Per socket data transfer on Multiple Client every second

Tags: c#, client, client-server

I am programming a server, which is sending to the clients serialized-XML data every 0 - 1 sec.  My problem is the server sends data to clients and it works a bit slowly when 1000 clients connect.  I am using TCP only.

Is there another method or architecture to solve this problem?  Is it possible to solve this problem with web services?  The last question: does it gives the same effect if I use 1 port or more ports (10-100) for all clients?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ports won't make a difference to performance. They're just informational slots to pipe traffic into.

Plain TCP is probably going to be the fastest solution. The performance issue probably lies with your code, rather than the architecture. Try running some performance analysis on it to see where the CPU usage and memory allocation hotspots are.